# emacs global-set-key M-, seems to be overridden and does not work after upgrading some packages in emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

Here is my .emacs content. Can someone please help.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-,") 'pop-tag-mark)
(setq projecthome "/tmp/myproject")
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (let ((ess-build-tags-command "rtags('%s', recursive = TRUE, pattern = '\\\\.[RrSs](rw)?$',ofile = '%s')")
                  (my-tags-file (concat projecthome "/R/TAGS")))
              (ess-build-tags-for-directory (concat projecthome "/R/") (concat projecthome "/R/TAGS"))
              (sleep-for 5)
              (visit-tags-table my-tags-file)
          )))
```

Comment: The question risks being closed because it is unclear. Please specify exactly what the problem is. What are the symptoms? What makes you think that the global binding of `M-,` is not `pop-tag-mark`? And reduce any code you show to what is relevant to the question.

Comment: What command does it say `M-,` runs when you do `M-x describe-key` and then hit `M-,`?